# Loading file random text to label

Tags: app-inventor

I want to load a file from my computer into the MIT App Inventor. The file should have these lines. "Nice", "Well Done", "Good Job".

When a user press a button, a label will have the text "Nice", "Well Done" or "Good Job". I want it to choose random. How can i do this? I also have a file with over 200 quotes in it, that I want to load, and not write them as text manually.

How can i do this?

[image]

When i press randomtextButton on phone, i get error:

`Error 2102: The file "myText.txt" could not be found`

The file is uploaded in the designer screen -> Media -> "Upload File..." What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming, you stored each item in a separate line in the file like this:

Nice
Well Done
Good Job

To read a file from the assets, use // together with the file name. In the `File.GotText` event you have to convert the text first into a list using the `split` block (just split at **\n**, which is new line) to get a list and then use the `pick a random item` block.

Btw. it helps to read the tooltips of the `File.ReadFrom` block or the [documentation](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/storage.html#File), how the file component works...

[image]

A very good way to learn App Inventor is to read the free Inventor's Manual here in the AI2 free online eBook   http://www.appinventor.org/book2 ... the links are at the bottom of the Web page.  The book 'teaches' users how to program with AI2 blocks.
There is a free programming course here http://www.appinventor.org/content/CourseInABox/Intro  and the aia files for the projects in the book are here:  http://www.appinventor.org/bookFiles
How to do a lot of basic things with App Inventor are described here:  http://www.appinventor.org/content/howDoYou/eventHandling  .

Also do the tutorials http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/tutorials.html to learn the basics of App Inventor, then try something and follow the
 [Top 5 Tips: How to learn  App Inventor](https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php)